# Can't get id from Auth::check

Tags: laravel

I try to get user id in the Laravel app. In my User.php I added this code

```
if (Auth::check())
{
   $id = Auth::id();
   echo '<script>console.log($id)</script>';
}
```

I get below given error:-

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $id is not defined

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mingling the logic of JS and PHP :)))

```
if (Auth::check())
{
   $id = Auth::id();
   echo '<script>console.log('.$id.')</script>';
}
```

OR simply echo it?

```
if (Auth::check())
{
   $id = Auth::id();
   echo $id;
}
```

OR you could use a double quote if you really wanna print it under script tags with your current format:

```
if (Auth::check())
{
   $id = Auth::id();
   echo "<script>console.log($id)</script>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Access Id like this:

```
$id = Auth::user()->id;
```

Comment: `Auth::id()` is a short form of what you have mentioned.